Поиск максимума в словаре, значениями которого являются списки, словари и списки словарей
Дано
Есть словарь, значениями которого являются списки, словари и списки словарей. Все ключи - str. Все значения самого низкого уровня вложености - int.
Для примера:
d = {
  "key1": [3, 5, 6, 7, 15, 16],
  "key2": {
    "key3": 5,
    "key4": 20,
    "key5": 12
  },
  "key6": [
    {"key7": 5, "key8": 10},
    {"key7": 8, "key8": 10},
  ],
  "key9": [1, 7, 4, 2,]
}

При этом количество значений каждого типа может быть произвольно любым.
Требуется
Надо найти максимум из всех значений.
Мое решение заключается в том, чтобы проходя по ключам проверять тип и далее получать значения способами подходящими для каждого типа, можно их, например, складывать в множество и потом взять максимум, вот типа того:
total_set = set()
for k in d:
    if isinstance(d[k], list):
        if isinstance(d[k][0], int | float):
            total_set |= set(d[k])
        else:
            for vl in d[k]:
                total_set |= set(vl.values())
    else:
        total_set |= set(d[k].values())
print(max(total_set))

А как-то не в лоб можно? Попроще?

А зачем вам собирать численные значения в set, если сразу можно считать максимум?

Собственно, тоже не понимаю, зачем вы сначала собираете set, а уже из него извлекаете максимум, если можно напрямую записывать его в переменную. А что касается вашего вопроса, то структура изощрённая и, вероятно, лучше, чем за O(N), решить не выйдет. Вам в любом случае нужно пройти по всем элементам. В теории, если есть возможность менять вид структуры, то можно создать структуру, в которой каждый "контейнер" будет знать максимальное значение всех содержащихся в нём элементов, вычисляемое при их добавлении.

@MBo у меня была такая логика (я не берусь утверждать, что она правильная) - в этой структуре очень многие объекты (например, списки) могут почти полностью или полностью повторяться. И я решал, что оптимальнее - 1. N раз брать максимум от одинаковых (почти) коллекций, или 2. сначала схлопнуть все эти коллекции в уникальное множество, количество элементов которого будет существенно меньше чем сумма длин всех коллекций и потом взять максимум. В результате, чисто умозрительно победил второй вариант, но я совершенно не настаиваю, что он лучше, чем первый. Надо мерять.

Вам непременно придётся проверять каждый элемент. В случае простого максимума вы выполняете только N операций сравнения. В случае множеств вы выполняете для каждого элемента внесение во множество - это не менее N более сложных операций, плюс расходы на поддержание структуры множества, плюс поиск максимума в оставшихся во множестве элементах. Что может сыграть положительную роль во втором случае, если подсписки великИ по объёму - большинство операций выполняются низкоуровневой библиотекой.

Есть еще вариант, который не займет памяти (по памяти будет O(1)).

Инициализируем переменную, например, maximum = float("-inf").
Далее проходимся по всем значениям. Чтобы просматривать структуру в глубину, лучше подойдет рекурсия.


O(1) и "проходимся по всем значениям" понятия не совместимы.

@kristal - там же написано, что O(1) по памяти

@Xander, да, верно, почему-то упустил, спасибо что поправили
